# Getting the max value of a table by gruop

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

i'm kind of new in sql, right now I'm trying to get the best average for each group(GRP) and i have this table.

[image]

[Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ho7hY.jpg)

i'm tryng to get something like this, but im not sure how to do it

[image]
[expected table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fC9MX.jpg)

Comment: The question marked as duplicate source doesn't max an average, but maxes a simple column

Comment: Please post the query or queries you have tried already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  *
from    (
        select  dense_rank() over (partition by grp order by g_avg desc) as rn
        ,       *
        from    (
                select  sid
                ,       grp
                ,       first
                ,       last
                ,       avg(points) as g_avg
                from    YourTable
                group by
                        sid
                ,       grp
                ,       first
                ,       last
                )
        )
where   rn = 1
```